# AppFabric Powershell New-Cache Exception

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2008, appfabric

I've just finished an AppFabric install on my prod server after getting this to work without an issues on my dev environment. AppFabric installed without an issues and is running, but when I try to create a new named cache (ps: New-Cache ClickUrls) I get the following exception:

New-Cache : ErrorCode:SubStatus:Error: Cache creation returned failure.

At line:1 char:10

- New-Cache <<<<
- CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Cache], DataCacheException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : ERRPS009,Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Commands.NewCacheCommand

Any insight into why its not working? This was a non-issue on my dev environment.

cheers in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open 'Services and Applications' console and check the status of 'AppFabric Caching Service'. On my box (Windows 7 x86) it was configured as manual and not started just after installation.

Answer (score 8):

When you run the powershell you must run it as administrator or else you will have this and other errors.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and running the Powershell as administrator did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot to go on there! I just Googled that error code ERRPS009, but according to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921008.aspx) all it means is 'Cache not created' :-(

What do you get if you run `Test-CacheConfigAvailability`?. You might also want to check the installation log as detailed [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/how-to-research-appfabric-installation-errors.aspx) for any issues that failed silently during the install.

Comment: Test-CacheConfigAvailability doesn't return anything. Based on docs thats good (appears an exception would be thrown otherwise). I'll dig into the install log when time allows and post back.

Comment: So I uninstalled AppFabric and reinstalled it. I remembered there being an issue during the initial install - reinstalling allowed me to reproduce it. It was as follows, 1) install went fine 2) open ps, run Start-CacheCluster -- I get the following error:

Comment: Start-CacheCluster : ErrorCode<ERRCAdmin032>:SubStatus<ES0001>:Invalid operatio
n encountered on P4PINTERACTIVE:AppFabricCachingService : Cannot open AppFabric
CachingService service on computer 'P4PINTERACTIVE'.
At line:1 char:19
+ Start-CacheCluster <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-CacheCluster], Data
   CacheException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ERRCAdmin032,Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching
   .Commands.StartCacheClusterCommand

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error.

Here's how I fixed it:

1. Windows Button > services.msc > Hit [Enter].
2. Right-click on 'AppFabric Caching Service'.
3. Click 'Stop'.
4. Go back to PowerShell and create a new cache.

**Success!**

---

**EDIT:** Depending on your setup, an `iisreset` command might not hurt either.